# robocopy wierd behavior for /copyall

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, robocopy

When I use robocopy with /copyall flag, the **1st attempt** for the files will be display as "New Files" and the output will display the number of new files copied and other transfer/bytes information.

The **2nd attempt** for using the same path + command will display **"Modified"** for the same files even though there **are absolutely *NO* changes or any modifications at all**/the output will still display "x files copied and bytes etc info"

The 3rd and subsequent attempt will then behave normally (output will not show any new/modified files transferred)

See output below

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.SG-EQUINIX> robocopy B:\MSSQL\Test\test1 \\sqldr1\Backup\Test /copyall

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Monday, 15 May 2017 12:37:33 AM
   Source : B:\MSSQL\Test\test1\
     Dest : \\sqldr1\Backup\Test\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /COPYALL /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           2    B:\MSSQL\Test\test1\
100%        **New File**              34.8 m        IBXX_backup_2017_04_19_173001_8474121 - Copy.trn
100%        **New File**              34.8 m        nn.trn

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         0         0         0         0
   Files :         2         2         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   69.65 m   69.65 m         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:15   0:00:15                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :             4723113 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :             270.258 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Monday, 15 May 2017 12:37:49 AM

PS C:\Users\administrator.SG-EQUINIX> robocopy B:\MSSQL\Test\test1 \\sqldr1\Backup\Test /copyall

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Monday, 15 May 2017 12:38:11 AM
   Source : B:\MSSQL\Test\test1\
     Dest : \\sqldr1\Backup\Test\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /COPYALL /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           2    B:\MSSQL\Test\test1\
            **Modified**              34.8 m        IBXX_backup_2017_04_19_173001_8474121 - Copy.trn
            **Modified**              34.8 m        nn.trn

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         0         0         0         0
   Files :         2         2         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   69.65 m   69.65 m         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :           2282592000 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :           130610.961 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Monday, 15 May 2017 12:38:11 AM
```

Anyone has any idea why ?

============== Added below to reply to comments ===============

Both SRC and DEST have the same filesystem (NTFS) , sector and segment size.

I have also using the powershell command getItem-Property on the source file and destination file after it is being robocopied over.

Their creation,access,write time are absolutely the same.  Yet..the 2nd attempt of the same robocopy command still show the same file being copied over as "Modified" although there is actually no actual copying over (the "Time" reflected as 0).

Tried the /FFT flag, same behaviour, 2nd attempt still show files as Modified.
When there is no change at all to the creation,access,write time of the same file on both sides.

My braincells are dying..

Comment: I can't repro. There must be something in your environment that's involved.

Comment: You're using a B: drive - is that a USB that's formatted as FAT?

Comment: Noob - Look over here: https://superuser.com/questions/1026184/use-robocopy-to-mirror-source-but-ignore-timestamp/1026196#1026196... you may just need to use the `/FFT` switch which is probably where Chris was going with that comment next.

Comment: to all - I added comment to the original post, please take a look

Comment: Have you tried using the /m switch?

Comment: Do you get this same behavior if you run the command through Command Prompt instead of PowerShell?

Comment: @SturdyErde  what does "reset archive attribute" actually do ? ->unmark the archive attribute on the source file ? even if so, how will it help ?

Comment: The archive attribute indicates whether or not the file has been backed up. When a file is modified, the archive attribute (A) is turned on. When the file gets backed up, the (A)rchive attribute is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to get the "modified" to show in a robocopy of matching files at source/destination across time zones.  see some of the robocopy definitions below.

[image]